# Apache DS LDAP Server Fails to Start

Tags: ldap, apacheds

I have a fresh ApacheDS (Version: 2.0.0.v20210717-M17) install on a Windows 11 on ARM. I have Java SDK 17 (LTS). I created a first server with all the defaults and it seems that the first time it started correctly.

I then tried to import some LDIF but it failed saying that the server was down. And yes, from that moment, I cannot start the server any longer. I even tried removing the server, creating a new one, etc...Still, it won't start.

If I check the logs, this is what I see:

```
[12:27:25] INFO [org.apache.directory.server.UberjarMain] - Starting the service.
[12:27:30] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.42.2.27.8.5.1' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[12:27:30] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.841' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[12:27:30] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.3.6.1.4.1.4203.1.9.1.2' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[12:27:30] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.319' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[12:27:30] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.DefaultAttribute] - ERR_13207_VALUE_ALREADY_EXISTS The value '1.2.840.113556.1.4.528' already exists in the attribute (supportedControl)
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.api.ldap.model.entry.Value] - MSG_13202_AT_IS_NULL ()
[12:27:31] WARN [org.apache.directory.server.core.DefaultDirectoryService] - You didn't change the admin password of directory service instance 'default'.  Please update the admin password as soon as possible to prevent a possible security breach.
```

Any idea what may be wrong?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was Java 17. Moving to Java 11 made it work.

Answer (score 0):

Installing JDK-11 was the the simplest solution. It worked after setting java classpath to jdk 11